# PHPWord docx margin on Mac with LibreOffice

Tags: macos, docx, phpword

I´m exporting a docx file generated with PHPWord 0.13.
On Windows with LibreOffice everythink looks perfect.
[image: Windows Margin]
But on Mac with LibreOffice the the blue box has an printmargin.
[image: Mac Margin]

The Code for the blue box.

```
$section->addImage(
    '/path/to/img',
    [
        'positioning'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_RELATIVE,
        'width'         => '800',
        'height'        => '256',
        'align'         => 'center',
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
    ]
);
```

I don´t find the problem.
I hope the problem is not: it´s an docx file oepned in LibreOffice

**UPDATE 2016.06.28**
My solution:

```
$sectionStyle = $section->getStyle();
$sectionStyle->setMarginRight(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(0));
$sectionStyle->setMarginLeft(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(0));

$section->addImage(
    '/path/to/img',
    [
        'positioning'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_RELATIVE,
        'width'         => 800,
        'height'        => '256',
        'align'         => 'center',
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
    ]
);

$sectionStyle->setMarginRight(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(2));
$sectionStyle->setMarginLeft(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(2));
```

Comment: Not a solution, but do you actually need an editable document? If not you could, and should, use PDF.

Comment: I need a editable document.